# Pass td value to another page using from action in php

Tags: javascript, php

Hi guys I am trying to pass my `<td>` ID value to another page using POST form action

I have already did by using get method through `<a>` tag. I would like to pass through form hidden.
Here is my `<td>` and `<a>` tag

```
<td>
    <center>
       <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" href="editcompany.php?id=<?php echo $row->cid; ?>">
            <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
        </a>
    </center>
</td>
```

Can any one explain me how to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use <input type="hidden"> to store the value.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, use this in your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row->cid; ?>">
```

Comment: yes thats fine.but i have to use use from inside td right?how to use that

Comment: why would you have to use it from inside td? hidden type does not have any impact on view. Just make sure to use it from within <form></form> tag

Comment: how can i pass my edit company.php page and how can i get that id in editcompany.php page?

Comment: Why do you want to send it as POST? Get is fine for that purpose

Comment: Even if you want to send it as POST, you can put action="edit.php" with the hidden parameter as value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173859/discussion-between-penguine-and-suresh).